# Identifying the algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, mathematical-physics, clifford-algebras

In order to solve an obscure (physics) problem I have been considering whose details are not important, I am looking for elements (I am thinking in terms of matrices and their products but this may probably be relaxed to something more abstract) $A$, $B$ and $C$ which satisfy

$C^2 = 0$,
$A \cdot C + C \cdot A = I$
and
$B \cdot C + C \cdot B = -A^2$

where $I$ is the identity element (matrix) and $0$ is the zero element (matrix).

They can also be written more systematically as requirements on the anticommutators with $C$:

$A \cdot C + C \cdot A = I$,
$B \cdot C + C \cdot B = -A^2$,
$C\cdot C + C \cdot C = 0$,

such that

$\{ A,C \} = I$, $\{ B,C\} = -A^2$ and $\{C,C\} = 0$ where $\{X,Y\} = X \cdot Y + Y \cdot X$.

I have little knowledge about abstract algebras and even less on their representation by matrices.

Do you recognise any interesting structure in this? My first thought was that it could somehow be related to Clifford algebras.

I am a physics student and apologise for any description of mathematics that is ambiguous or wrong.

Comment: Which physics context is this? (Something fermion-related, I imagine...)

Comment: If an algebraist is looking for elements satisfying those relations, she can just create them by quotienting the noncommutative polynomial ring in $A,B,C$ by those relations. (Whenever quotienting by relations there is always the risk of collapsing more structure than one would desire, of course, and we often want to safety-check our structure because of that concern.)

Comment: @Semiclassical I have an equation of motion that I am trying to take the square root of in the manner of Dirac. This square root may be bringing in something that looks like a Clifford algebra. This is very experimental and I am only playing around. However, having isolated the above structure, I wanted to hear from the community if anything abstract can be said about the elements (matrices) that will facilitate the "square root" procedure.

Comment: I for one would be very interested in seeing your equation of motion.

Comment: As would I. Some background would probably help us as well, since even if it's obscure there may still be relevant literature. @RobertLewis

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I wanted to take a Wiener process $dW$ and see if its square root would yield anything interesting, defining a Brownian motion over an algebra instead. So I look for a Brownian motion $A \cdot dW + B \cdot dt + C$ such that $(A \cdot dW + B \cdot dt + C)\cdot (A \cdot dW + B \cdot dt + C) = dW$. By rules of Itô calculus $dW^2 =dt$, $dW \cdot dt =0$ and $dt^2 = 0$ which will yield the algebra of $A$, $B$ and $C$ constrained as defined in the beginning. I realise that I may not know what I am doing but I am playing around!

Comment: We actually have tags for stochastic calculus, so I think you'd be fine to post the problem in the full context as you understand it. Otherwise I'm not sure you're likely to get answers which will be very satisfying.

Answer (score 2):

The free algebra $A$ generated by three letters $a$, $b$ and $c$ subject to the relations 
$$cc=0, \qquad ca=1-ac, \qquad cb=-aa-bc$$
has as a basis the set of non-commutative monomials in the three letters in which $c$ does not appear to the left of any letter. It contains the free algebra $B$ on $a$ and $b$, and in fact $A$ is a free left $B$-module with basis $\{1,c\}$. In particular, the algebra $A$ is infinite dimensional.

Suppose we have a representation of the algebra $A$ on a vector space $V$. Let $K=\ker c$. We have $aK\cap K=0$: if $v$ is in this intersection, it is equal to $aw$ for some $w\in K$ and $cv=0$, and it follows that $v=cav+acv=caaw=aacw=0$, because the relations imply that $c$ and $aa$ commute. On the other hand, if $v\in V$, we have $v=acv+cav$ and $cav\in K$ and $cv\in K$, so that $c\in aK+K$. We conclude that $V=aK\oplus K$. As $K$ intersects the kernel of $a$ trivially, the map $k\in K\mapsto ak\in aK$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces, whose inverse is $x\in aK\mapsto cx\in K$.

We have $aaK\subseteq K$. The module $V$ is in fact completely determined by the linear map $\phi:x\in aK\mapsto ax\in K$. This showws that one can classify modules over the algebra $B$ using Jordan canonical forms of size half the dimension of $V$ (for the map $aa:K\to K$). Maybe someone with more energy can see what happens if you include $b$ into this, but it does not look primising.

Comment: This follows from Bergman's diamond lemma applied to the lexicographic monomial order with $c>b>a$ and the relations I wrote.

Comment: Thank you very much for you effort! Much appreciated. I will need some time to study your answer in detail.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an explicit representation in terms of matrices, you can just brute force the given relations as $2*2$ matrices and take into account that since you wanted $C$ to be a nilpotent matrix, there exists a basis such that $C=((0,1),(0,0))$ (sorry about the typesetting). So without loss of generality you can take this to be your $C$ and just calculating the rest gives solutions $A=((a,b),(1,-a))  B=((x,y),(-a^2-b,-x))$ if I calculated correctly. However no idea if this helps you at all.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, upon writing down the conditions of the algebra, this search of the explicit representation by brute force in terms of $2 \times 2$ matrices was also my next move. However, I wrote here to ask about the abstract properties. Nevertheless, what you have written is still useful! Thank you.